# Cloning builder process: Operation not permitted when using Nix (under Linux) update channel

Tags: nix, nixpkgs

I use Arch Linux `4.19.15-1-lts #1 SMP Sun Jan 13 13:53:52 CET 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. I do also have Nix installed: `nix-env (Nix) 2.2`.

I've never had any problems until the recent update to version `2.2`. I always do the upgrades/updates with these two steps:

```
$ nix-channel --update
...
$ nix-env --upgrade
...
```

...but after the recent `2.2` update I can't find a way to make `nix-channel --update` work anymore. I'm always getting these errors:

```
error: cloning builder process: Operation not permitted
error: unable to start build process
error: program '/nix/store/876x7a35qbn3q062b6zcz6va88m0990d-nix-2.2/bin/nix-env' failed with exit code 1
```

...even if I do rollback the previous operation(s):

```
$ nix-channel --update 
unpacking channels...
error: cloning builder process: Operation not permitted
error: unable to start build process
error: program '/nix/store/876x7a35qbn3q062b6zcz6va88m0990d-nix-2.2/bin/nix-env' failed with exit code 1
$ nix-channel --rollback 
switching from generation 40 to 39
$ nix-channel --update 
unpacking channels...
error: cloning builder process: Operation not permitted
error: unable to start build process
error: program '/nix/store/876x7a35qbn3q062b6zcz6va88m0990d-nix-2.2/bin/nix-env' failed with exit code 1
```

This is what I have in the update list:

```
$ nix-channel --list 
nixpkgs https://nixos.org/channels/nixpkgs-unstable
```

...and eventually I can't even delete that:

```
$ nix-channel --remove nixpkgs 
uninstalling 'nixpkgs-19.03pre165281.7d864c6bd63'
error: cloning builder process: Operation not permitted
error: unable to start build process
error: program '/nix/store/876x7a35qbn3q062b6zcz6va88m0990d-nix-2.2/bin/nix-env' failed with exit code 1
```

> I would like to avoid a reinstall.

---

**UPDATE**

I couldn't wait! O:)

I went ahead and removed the current installation...and when I do a fresh install I basically got the same result:

```
$ sh <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2476  100  2476    0     0   5417      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  5406
downloading Nix 2.2.1 binary tarball for x86_64-linux from 'https://nixos.org/releases/nix/nix-2.2.1/nix-2.2.1-x86_64-linux.tar.bz2' to '/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.n5vqvsi4Uq'...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.5M  100 22.5M    0     0  4016k      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:-- 4377k
Note: a multi-user installation is possible. See https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#sect-multi-user-installation
performing a single-user installation of Nix...
directory /nix does not exist; creating it by running 'mkdir -m 0755 /nix && chown x80486 /nix' using sudo
[sudo] password for x80486: 
copying Nix to /nix/store.................................
initialising Nix database...
Nix: creating /home/x80486/.nix-profile
installing 'nix-2.2.1'
error: cloning builder process: Operation not permitted
error: unable to start build process
/tmp/nix-binary-tarball-unpack.n5vqvsi4Uq/unpack/nix-2.2.1-x86_64-linux/install: unable to install Nix into your default profile
```

...so looks like there is, in general, something going on with Linux (or specifically the distro that use) and Nix.

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with a  fresh install on a different distro.   When I switch to the previous version of nix ( curl https://nixos.org/releases/nix/nix-2.1.3/install | sh ) the problem goes away.   So I think it might be more accurate to say there's something going on with nix-2.2.1

Comment: Interesting; I didn't think about it. I think I'll stick with a lower version for a while then. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the suggestion in [this comment](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2633#issuecomment-455788240) resolves the problem:

```
sysctl kernel.unprivileged_userns_clone=1
```

Comment: That didn't do it for me. What kernel do you have installed? I have now `uplink 4.19.16-1-lts #1 SMP Thu Jan 17 07:35:45 CET 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`...and still have the same problem when I try to install Nix via: `sh <(curl https://nixos.org/nix/install) --no-daemon`.

Comment: I have `➜  ~ uname -a`: `Linux morpork 4.20.3-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jan 16 22:38:58 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 4):

[Nix uses quite a lot of flags for the clone](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/blob/master/src/libstore/build.cc#L2216), mainly to detach some linux namespaces.  I expect your system doesn't support some of these for *unprivileged* processes.  IIRC some distros chose that because of security concerns.

Comment: I truly think that's the case. I opened up an Issue in their GitHub repository but so far I haven't received any feedback. If they concur with this, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @x80486 Could you provide a link to the issue please?

Comment: It's filed under [NixOS/nix](https://github.com/NixOS/nix/issues/2633/)